# How to display the vaule(dependent value) when we select one item form the list of values in Android SDK?

Tags: android

Am new to this Android SDK platform,so could you people help me out to solve my issue.
so lets discuss brief about my issue, am developing small application in which am using sppiner to list all country states and zip codes so my question is when i select one country state in a list it should automatically populate and display its corresponding zip code

**below is my main.xml file**

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
 android:padding="12dip"
 android:layout_height="40dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
 />
```

**here is my Activity class**

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class EriePremium extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.States, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Zip, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(adapter1); 
}
```

}

**and my array list array.xml file**

Alabama
        Alaska
        American Samoa
        Arizona
        Arkansas
        California
        Colorado
        Connecticut
        Delaware
        District of Columbia
        Florida
        Georgia
        Guam
        Hawaii
        Idaho
        Illinois

1001
        1002
        1003
        1004
        1005
        1006
        1007
        1008
        1009
        1010
        1011
        1012
        1013
        1014
        1015
        1016

Awaiting for response

Thanks in advance,
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

**This is tested and (works bi-directionally)**

**EriePremium.java**

```
package com.example.statezip;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class EriePremium extends Activity 
{

public Spinner zipspinner,statespinner;


protected void onCreate(Bundle mbfSplash) 
{
        super.onCreate(mbfSplash);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setupZip();
        setupState();

}

public void setupZip() 
{

    zipspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.zipspinner);
//  List<String> ziplist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> zipAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.zip, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    zipAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    zipspinner.setAdapter(zipAdapter);
    zipspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new zipOnClickListener());
}
private void setupState()
{
    statespinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.statespinner);
//    List<String> statelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stateAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    stateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    statespinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
    statespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new stateOnClickListener());
}

    public class stateOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
    {
        @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) 
        {
             zipspinner.setSelection(pos);//parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        }



        @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
    public class zipOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
    {
        @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) 
        {
            statespinner.setSelection(pos);//parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        }



        @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}//class
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="top|left" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/statespinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:entries="@array/state"
        android:prompt="@string/state" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/zipspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statespinner"
        android:entries="@array/zip"
        android:prompt="@string/zip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TemoActivity.java**

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="zip">zip</string>
<string name="state">state</string>
<string name="title">state/zip</string>

<string-array name="state">
<item>Alabama Alaska</item>
<item>American Samoa</item>
<item>Arizona</item>
<item>Arkansas</item>
<item>California</item>
<item>Colorado</item>
<item>Connecticut</item>
<item>Delaware District of Columbia</item>
<item>Florida</item>
<item>Georgia</item>
```

.....
   < /string-array>

```
<string-array name="zip">
<item>1001</item>
<item>1002</item>
<item>1003</item>
<item>1004</item>
<item>1005</item>
<item>1006</item>
<item>1007</item>
<item>1008 1009</item>
<item>1010</item>
<item>1011</item>
```

......
< /string-array>